# using ajax how to show the value after success without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am adding the value to database by using ajax after adding i want to display the value in front end but now after success i am using `window.location` to show the data because of this the page  getting refresh,i don't want to refresh the page to show the data ,anyone guide me how  to do this.

below is my ajax

```
$(function() {
    $(".supplierpriceexport_button").click(function() {

    var pricefrom = $("#pricefrom").val();
    var priceto =  $("#priceto").val();
    var tpm =  $("#tpm").val();
    var currency =  $("#currency").val();


    var dataString = 'pricefrom='+ pricefrom +'&priceto='+priceto+'&tpm='+tpm+'&currency='+currency;


    if(pricefrom=='')
    {
    alert("Please Enter Some Text");
    }
    else
    {
    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "supplierpriceexport/insert.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $("#display").after(html);

    window.location = "?action=suppliertargetpiceexport";
    $("#flash").hide();
    }
    });
    } return false;
    });
    });
```

Comment: what is the corresponding code for action=suppliertargetpiceexport"?

Comment: you want to first show the response ,then redirect,right?

Comment: action=suppliertargetpiceexport" is the page shows the data \

Answer (score 2):

The code that you are using to post the data needs to return some meaningful data, JSON is useful for this, but it can be HTML or other formats.

To return your response as JSON from PHP, you can use the `json_encode()` function:

```
$return_html = '<h1>Success!</h1>';
$success = "true";

json_encode("success" => $success, "html_to_show" => $return_html);
```

In this piece of code, you can set your dataType or JSON and return multiple values including the HTML that you want to inject into the page (DOM):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "supplierpriceexport/insert.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,

    //Set the type of data we are expecing back
    dataType: json

    success: function(return_json){

        // Check that the update was a success
        if(return_json.success == "true")
        {
            // Show HTML on the page (no reload required)
            $("#display").after(return_json.html_to_show);
        }
        else
        {
            // Failed to update
            alert("Not a success, no update made");
        }
});
```

You can strip out the window.location altogether, else you won't see the DOM update.

Comment: Nowadays you would probably use ReactJS to show values on the page in a template, rather than returning full blown HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to return the values that you need from the `ajax` function.Something like this might do.

In your `insert.php`

`echo or return` the `data` at the end of the `function` that needs to be populated into the page

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "supplierpriceexport/insert.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
             //Now you have obtained the data that was was returned from the function
             //if u wish to insert the value into an input field try
           $('#input_field').val(data); //now the data is pupolated in the input field 

     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `window.location = "?action=suppliertargetpiceexport";`

This will redirect to the page `suppliertargetpiceexport`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "supplierpriceexport/insert.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $('#your_success_element_id').html(html); // your_success_element_id is your element id where the html to be populated
        $("#flash").hide();
    }
});
```

`your_success_element_id` is your element id where the html to be populated

Comment: what is  your_success_element_id i didn't get that

Comment: `your_success_element_id` can be a `div` `id` in your page.